# Add an icon to Windows default "New scan"

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am configuring a computer for my old man and he is frequently scanning documents. He has a bad memory and is not very good with computers so I am trying to make things as simple as possible for him.

To scan a document we have to right/click on the printer icon and choose "Start scan". This seems to be too much to remember for him.

Is there a way to make a shortcut to the "New scan" window (second picture) so that all he has to do is to double click on an icon (that I can name "Scan")?

[image][image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might work, but I have not tested it in Win 10 yet. Works on Win 7

Right click on an open area on the desktop and select New > Shortcut.

The location of the item would be

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c wiaacmgr
```

This script will open the cmd prompt, then launch the Windows Scan tool. It will also close the cmd prompt, so your father won't be confused by the extra open window.

Click on Next, then title your shortcut New Scan.

You'll see a new icon on the desktop. Test it out. If it works to your liking, right click on it and select "Change Icon". You can then select an icon that would be a good visual for your father to remember.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'd add some images, but I can't upload to imgr from work. I don't know if the scan app will be the same as the one that launches from right clicking on the printer icon.

Comment: Great! Hopefully this keeps your dad scanning without multiple calls to "tech support"..aka you.

Comment: That does the trick @jrichall! How did you find out what the command is? Coming from Unix I'm really frustrated setting up my family's Windows machine because I can't ever figure out what is going on behind the windows... even process manager didn't show the Start Scan window in the list.

Comment: Honestly @Matt I wish I had a better answer, but I ended up googling the "Windows Scanner Tool" and it came up. I already knew about the `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c` function for running things directly from the command prompt. the "/c" closes the cmd window after the function has been run,

Comment: @Arete I did ...?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I'm actually doing the same, setting up my dad's new computer. So there's an application in C:\Windows\System32 called wiaacmrg.exe that opens a scan console, so you can make a shortcut to it and it has an icon with scanner next to a camera so it's just about perfect.

Answer (score 0):

> PowerShell script that creates a shortcut to scan on the desktop named "Scan":

```
$lnk = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut(([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop'))+"\Scan.lnk");
$lnk.TargetPath = "wiaacmgr";
$lnk.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

or easily go to C:WINDOWS:SYSTEM 32 and find the ''wiaacmrg''. Right click and add a shortcut to desktop. In fact all the application of our PC is in System32 where you can make shortcuts.Hope I helped!!